# A problem with FormClosing property

Tags: c#, winforms, events

i want to set a property that when the user clicks on X button in the title bar it check for some condition if all conditions are true then exit if no then do nothing and return to the form ..

but i noticed that FormClosing property exit the application howevere are my conditions ...
so how to do my scenario ?!?

i'm using visual studio 2005 - C#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have already created the handler for the FormClosing event, just set the `FormClosingEventArgs.Cancel` property to True to cancel the closure of the form.

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
  if(myConditionsAreMet == false)
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In the `FormClosing` event, set `e.Cancel` to `true` before returning.